# HTTP tracking - call url while requesting specific url

Tags: http, url, action, tracking

Is there any windows program, that allows you to track https requests and do some action while requesting specific URL? In this case I would like to call another URL.

For example if I request google.com URL, I would also like to call mydomain.com URL.

Comment: hi, interesting, this might be of interest https://httptoolkit.tech/